# Toggle class on multiple items

Tags: jquery, menu

I need to toggle the 'bg' class on an opened menu item. It works fine if they're activated and deactivated one at a time. But when one is opened when another is already activated, then the class isn't added/removed properly. Cheers.

http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/31/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                  
    jQuery('.menu ul').hide();
    jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('a:first').toggleClass('bg');
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').toggle(0)
               .end().siblings('li').find('ul').hide(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: I doesn't understand what you means with "all messy"

Comment: Sorry, not a technical term probably :) I mean that in that case the class isn't added/removed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/39/

It uses this code:

```
jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function () {
    var target = jQuery(this).children('a');

    if(target.hasClass('bg')){
        target.removeClass('bg');
    }else{
        jQuery('.menu-item > a').removeClass('bg');
        target.addClass('bg');
    }

    jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
                .toggle(0)
                .end()
                .siblings('li')
                .find('ul')
                .hide();
});
```